# Range Validation - Exclude 0

Tags: c#, validation

I am new to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) programming and trying to put a range validator for `InterestRate` to ensure that the interest rate is between 0 and 100. 
I also want to check that 0 should **not** be included in the interest rate as it must be higher. This is what I have so far:

```
[Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "The interest rate should be between 0.00 to 100.00 ")]
public decimal InterestRate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you using this in MVC model or somewhere else? what kind of app you are writing?

Comment: So why not change it to `1` instead of `0` (`[Range(1, 100,.....`])?

Comment: @Igor I guess he is saying that it should not be absolute zero but it can be epsilon

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - at some point it will be persisted or used though and the data type of whatever store is used usually has some scalar constraint. Whatever that lowest value is that the constraint allows and meets the business use case should be what the OP chooses.

Comment: yup I am using a MVC model

Answer (score 2):

So why not change it to `1` or `0.01` or to whatever the lowest value is allowed to be instead of `0`?

```
[Range(0.01, 100, ErrorMessage = "The interest rate should be between 0.01 to 100.00 ")]
public decimal InterestRate { get; set; }
```